# IServiceProvider instance in .Net 6

Tags: .net-6.0, hangfire, service-provider

On my .Net 5 ASP.NET application at Startup.cs I have the follwing (for Hangfire):

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
...
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseActivator(new ServiceProviderJobActivator(serviceProvider));
...
}
```

I want to move to the .Net 6 way of configuration (in Program.cs), but I don't know how to get an instance of IServiceProvider to provide to the ServiceProviderJobActivator method.

The method is:

```
internal class ServiceProviderJobActivator : Hangfire.JobActivator
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public ServiceProviderJobActivator(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public override object ActivateJob(Type type)
    {
        return _serviceProvider.GetService(type);
    }
}
```

I have tried:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseActivator(new ServiceProviderJobActivator(app.Services));
```

I also tried:

```
    public override object ActivateJob(Type type)
    {
        return _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(type);
    }
```

but the ActivateJob returns null in both cases

Thanks

Comment: "I have tried builder.Services and also builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider() with no luck" - please be more specific.

Comment: @Dai I hope I clarified it

Answer (score 3):

For anyone looking how to get a `IServiceProvider` instance, after you call `builder.Build()` the `app.Services` property will resolve as an `IServiceProvider` instance.

Comment: I was looking for `app.ApplicationServices` (used in .NET 5), but as you stated that it's now `app.Services` (for .NET 6). Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like option 3 from [Upgrading a .NET 5 "Startup-based" app to .NET 6](https://andrewlock.net/exploring-dotnet-6-part-12-upgrading-a-dotnet-5-startup-based-app-to-dotnet-6/) ?

It should lead to something like :

```
var app = builder.Build();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseActivator(new ServiceProviderJobActivator(app.Services));
```